# ASP.NET: Response.AppendHeader, location 301 Moved Permanently, sending with custom headers

Tags: asp.net

I'm wondering how to send custom headers using a redirect, currently with no success. I’m attempting to do the following:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.AddHeader("X-PagePathNode", "/public/IPOs.aspx");
Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
Response.StatusCode = 301;
Response.AppendHeader("Location", "default.aspx");
Response.End();
```

When I’m looking at the Request object’s headers, the new header isn’t there. Looking at firebug, the following is happening. The page which is doing the location change has the new header. However the page the location has redirected too doesn’t contain the new header in the Request.

My Question is how to redirect to a new location with the new headers from redirect into the Request object of the new Location.

Essentially I want to be able to: `Request.Header[“X-PagePathNode"]`  on the page load to view the headers added from the redirect.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/243057/response-redirect-strips-header-referrer-possible-to-add-it-back

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a couple of different approaches you can try. Among your tools are [Session variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx), [cookies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.aspx), the [Referrer HTTP header](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx), and a query string.

From what I understand, you want to issue a HTTP 301 redirect from page `A` to page `B`, and from page `B`, you wish to acknowledge the fact that this redirect has taken place (and maybe add some additional headers or logic).

Here's a few approaches:

- From page `A`, set a `Session` variable, and check for its existance in page `B` (then you probably want to remove said `Session` variable).
- From page `A`, set a cookie, and check for its existence in page `B`.
- From page `B`, check `Request.UrlReferrer` and see if it's page `A`, then do your logic.

Comment: Appreciate the advice however I'm trying to avoid using sessions. UrlReferrer isn't what I'm after. I'm trying to pass a unique variable in header, in this scenario its a url to page for a specific action. cheers.

Comment: So you're redirecting from page A to page B, and you want to pass the value `/public/IPOs.aspx` to page B?

Comment: Yeah that's essentially want I'm trying do using headers. I can't use a session or querystrings.

Comment: Why not set a cookie? That's nothing more than using the `Set-Cookie` HTTP header, and you'll just need to check for its existence in page B. Without using Session, a cookie, or query string, I'm at a loss for other options.

Comment: I was hoping .NET would allow me to mod-headers on response-redirect action. I've already pointed out the alternatives such as a session, querystring and cookie. thanks for the response.

Comment: Using .NET doesn't give you any more power, it all boils down to the HTTP protocol (i.e. you'd be in the same boat if you were using PHP, Java, RoR, whatever).